# Printing a list in rows of a set length (Python)

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and having a hard time figuring out how to print a list in rows given these circumstances:

The list starts out empty and the computer generates random 2-digit integer entries, which are then appended to the list. Printing the list is easy enough, either in a single column or in a single line using

```
for i in list:
    print(i, end = "")
```

but what I want to do is print in rows of 4, ending the list with whatever the remainder is (e.g. a row of 3), so that the outcome would look something like this:

```
81  27  19  55
99  45  32  90
67  83  20  72
12  86  21
```

What is the best and most straightforward way to do this?

Edit: I forgot to clarify that I'm working in Python 3. Sorry about that.

Comment: I guess pprint is a good catch
https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter

Try playing with the width argument of the constructor

Comment: Divide your list into chunks of 4 ([link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python), [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)), and print each chunk on a line.

Answer (score 3):

There many ways to do this, as others have shown. One more:

```
for i in range(0, len(mylist), 4):
    print(*mylist[i:i+4], sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the modulus operator to recognize when you're on the 4th column and change the `end` value to `print`.

```
for i, val in enumerate(list):
    end = '\n' if (i + 1) % 4 == 0 else '  '
    print(val, end=end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a statement to drop in a newline every 4th item:

```
count = 1
for i in list:
    print(i, end = "")
    count += 1
    if count % 4 == 0:
        print('\n')
```

If you like indexing better:

```
for i in len(list):
    print(list[i], end = "")
    if i % 4 == 0:
        print('\n')
```

Does that solve the problem for you?

Comment: Why not `enumerate`?

Comment: I'm keeping the tech level low.  You might want to add enumerate as an alternate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ind, val in enumerate(yourList):
    if ind != 0 and ind % 4 == 0:
        print('\n')
    print(val, end=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your starting list of numbers:

```
numbers = [81, 27, 19, 55, 99, 45, 32, 90, 67, 83, 20, 72, 12, 86, 21]
```

I would first group them into separate lists:

```
grouped_numbers = [numbers[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(numbers),4)]
```

Then I would print out each group with a blank space in between them using the `join` function

```
for group_of_numbers in grouped_numbers:
    print (" ".join(map(str,group_of_numbers)))
```

Comment: OP seems to be using python 3.

Comment: I made changes for a run in python 3 without errors